# build server/continuous integration tool

Tags: maven, ant, jenkins, gnu-make, continuum

I am new to Build Servers/Continuous Integration, so I need a little guidance please. I need to choose a tool that meets the following requirements:

- Build Maven/Java, Python and C projects
- Run a general build script that performs all build jobs, perferably in python (since our existing script is python)
- After each build, deploy the build on an appliance server or VM and run sanity checks

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins seems to fit the bill pretty well.

- It's a de facto standard and probably the most used countinuous integration server
- Of course, it builds Java, but also Python and C (using make)
- And you can deliver the built version on a test server:

CMake :

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/cmakebuilder+Plugin

Python:

http://www.alexconrad.org/2011/10/jenkins-and-python.html
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Python+Plugin

Delivery pipeline:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin